# Undefined value when trying to test RxJS interval

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, testing, jasmine

I am executing initializeTimer method in ngOnInit hook. In initializeTimer I defined rxjs interval which is responsible for decrementing number passed in component Input. Now I want to test this method, however I get an error

```
Expected undefined to equal 9.
```

I have no idea how can I test this subscription. I read something about fakeAsync and tick, but it seems not work for me. As form me ngOnInit is not triggered.

Component

```
@Input() timeLeft: number;
timer: number;
observableTimer: Subscription;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.initializeTimer();
}

initializeTimer() {
  this.observableTimer = interval(1000).subscribe(val => {
    const timeLeft = this.timeLeft - val;
    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      this.onTimesUp();
    }
    this.timer = timeLeft;
  });
}
```

Test

```
it('expect timer to decrement', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.timeLeft = 10;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick(1000);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.timer).toEqual(9);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is a long standing bug with testing rxjs `interval` with `fakeAsync` and `tick`. You can read more about it under this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127).